# Where's this 1/2 coming from squaring the derivative for arc length?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am currently studying arc length in calculus 2 and I am having trouble understanding one of the solutions. I understand the concept and how the procedure works, but it seems like in a lot of problems you're adding on a 1/2 and bringing it in front of the integral, and I am not sure how or why.

[image: Here's the solution that I am confused about.]

Above is the image that shows the calculation for finding the derivative and then squaring that derivative. $1/2y^3 - 1/2y^{-3}$ squared should be $1/4y^6 + 1/4y^{-6}$.

Where is that $-1/2$ coming from in the 4th line of this solution? Is it so we can get a perfect square? And if so how do we just add that without changing the value of the equation?

Thanks!

Comment: there's the cross term in squaring. $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin The cross term 2ab would be (2)(1/2y^3)(- 1/2y^-3) which would be -1/2... ah this is where the -1/2 is coming from. I forgot about 2ab I just squared both a and b. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten the middle term in $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2 a b + b^2$ and that $y^3 \cdot y^{-3} = 1 \neq 0$.  Distibuting twice, then collecting...

\begin{align*}
 &\left( \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^3 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^{-3} \right)^2  \\
  &\qquad = \left( \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^3 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^{-3} \right) \left( \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^3 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^{-3} \right)  \\
 &\qquad = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^3\left( \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^3 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^{-3} \right) - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^{-3}\left( \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^3 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) y^{-3} \right)   \\
 &\qquad = \left( \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^6 - \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^{0} \right) - \left( \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^0 + \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^{-6} \right)  \\
 &\qquad = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^6 - \left( \frac{2}{4} \right) y^{0} + \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^{-6}  \\
 &\qquad = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^6 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) y^{-6}  \text{.}
\end{align*}